# How Does Apache Shiro Hash Salted Passwords?

Tags: passwords, shiro

If I use the [Apache Shiro command line tool](https://shiro.apache.org/command-line-hasher.html) to generate a password

```
java -jar shiro-tools-hasher-1.3.1-cli.jar -p -a SHA-512
```

and I use the password `password` I get

```
$shiro1$SHA-512$500000$wnjBM5pWpwN5784Aq7i7QA==$IqJ6XdwuKtCNqJCu982CzR6b4A3lnGp2F/WD8tmwVC7SAnOgeuUgtBbJ/ki9FqiIbX/ngF9RJd+5iy971d88cg==
```

The documentation says the hashing is salted by default and defaults to 500k iterations and testing it results in a different password each time so I assume it is.

I can now log in without specifying the salt anywhere though

```
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("jsmith", "password");
token.setRememberMe(true);
currentUser.login(token);
```

The only place I can see is that it must be in the hash.

If we look carefully we can see sections:

- `$shiro1` shows it is a Shiro hashed password
- `$SHA-512` shows the algorithm used
- `$500000` shows the number of iterations

The salt is probably after that section or at the end.

Is this a dangerous approach?

Are Apache Shiro exposing too much information here and making it somewhat easier to create an attack?

Comment: Password hashes *are not to be assumed secrets*. While having them confidential is 'part of' a good security chain, a good hash 'works' because it is not practical to brute-force - that is, the a corresponding plain text [ie. the password] cannot be recovered within the time an attacker is willing to spend. (Which is why using a SHA- of any nature for passwords makes me gag, even with many generations. These hashes are made to be well-optimizable in hardware and not designed specifically to increase computation.)

Comment: Also, I would suspect wnjBM5pWpwN5784Aq7i7QA== is the salt (as it is too small to be a SHA-512 result) and base-encoded separately.